# Updating Dependency Version in POM

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-release-plugin, maven-dependency-plugin

what is the best way to automatically update the dependency version in pom.xml , once a release for a dependency is built.

example:
A - Module Project
B - Uses Project A as a dependency project.

I want  to automate the process of updating the version for A in pom.xml automatically once a new release for A is built.

Can this be achieved for multiple projects?

We are using jenkins for CI

Regards,
Adnan Khan

Comment: If you already use maven-release-plugin than the update of the versions will be done? Did I miss something?

Comment: the dependency and the parent are separate modules and have different repository paths.In my case if I am building a release for dependency and new version gets updated to 1.1, I want this version to be automatically updated in the parent and other modules that using this.As of now we have a script in place that take a code check out of parent and updates the pushes the updated version on git.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `mvn versions:use-releases` followed by a commit on Jenkins before the release. This replaces all Snapshot versions by release versions if they exist.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I am unsure how mvn version will automatically update the dependency version and parent pom and other modules as they have different repository paths. We are pulling the code for parent and update the dependency version and push code so the release builds for other modules can be done.

Comment: My advice: Before building B, call an appropriate goal of the versions plugin to update the version of the dependency A. So this update will not be ad hoc when A is built, but just before B is built.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is using Renovate, it's a DevOps tool that already used in github and gitlab. It is also open source and you can use in in your self-hosted gitlab. it works not only with maven but also with all package manager like npm, pip, dockerhub, you can read more in the following link:

https://resources.whitesourcesoftware.com/blog-whitesource/welcome-to-whitesource-renovate